# jQuery not triggering change event on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to trigger the dropdown change event in jQuery (wordpress) but it's not working.

```
jQuery("select.buDropDown").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 }).trigger('change');
```

Running this in console only changes the selectedIndex to 0, but never triggers the change event that shows/hides certain elements on the page.

However, running this in console, everything triggers fine:

```
$("select.buDropDown").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 }).trigger('change');
```

I can't find any reasons why "$" would work but not "jQuery"

I tried wrapping it in:

```
jQuery(function($) {}
```

to be able to use $ instead, but in the wordpress code it still doesn't trigger the change events

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very odd behaviour, given that `$` is an alias for `jQuery`. Could you set up a working example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think he should add a snippet here

Comment: 1. Do yourself a favour now, stop using wordpress.
2. Encapsulate all of your jQuery and reassign `jQuery` to `$` like this `(function($){ ... /*code here*/ ... })(jQuery);`

Comment: @Panomosh if giving up is your solution then I wonder what system you're on now, because having issues with a CMS and then suggesting to change it as a solution each time there is a slight issue is counterproductive. Thanks for your suggestion on wrapping it to get $ back, but even doing that it doesn't trigger properly

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are calling trigger function after closing the each loop. This would never happen. The following would work:

```
jQuery("select.buDropDown").each(function() { 
    this.selectedIndex = 0;
    jQuery(this).trigger('change'); 
});
```

And by the way, the following statement:

```
$("select.buDropDown").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 }).trigger('change');
```

This means that select the collection of select.buDropDown and loop this collection and then trigger change on this collection. It will trigger change for only the first object in this collection. Not for the whole.

Comment: Thanks, I did do that in one of my attempts at getting it to work, however, running it in console with jQuery doesn't trigger the change event even if the selectedIndex changes successfully (using your method)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all contributions, you gave me some ideas I wanted to follow, and the following worked for my situation:

```
$("select.buDropDown").each(function() { 
        this.selectedIndex = 0;
     });
    $('select.buDropDown').parent().children('div').each(function() { $(this).hide(); });
```

Even though the dropdown's respective change events would have taken care of it, resetting to the original state is fine.